# Is it possible to have 'link_to' within application_helper.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a link in common. So I tried to make one in **application_helper.rb**.

But it seems not possible. How do I usually do this when I want to make link which will be used in common.

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def platform_search(genre_id)
      <%= link_to "<span class='btn btn-danger'>#{community.genre.name}</span>".html_safe, communities_path(:search => '' ,:genre => community.genre_id )%>
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `link_to` in helpers.
You are getting an error due to `<%=`.

The `<%= %>` is syntax for ERB (think views), not Ruby. Remove those delimiters.

Comment: It's erb, irb is the interactive console (not confusing whatsoever)

Comment: Addon comment about how to call the helper from the view... I stucked at least an hour because I was calling the helper with a dash `-` instead of an equal sign `=` in the view. I tried so many stupid things... This answer confirmed that `link_to` can be used just like this in an application_helper. So thanks!